# Google API Manager: Unable to add domain

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-messaging, google-search-console

From the Google API Manager, I am unable to add my domain even though it's verified in webmaster tools and central. I've verified both http and https.

The domain is a Heroku subdomain ie. xx.herokuapp.com.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding your domain in developer console? Any error popped up?

Comment: Yes, in the developer console under Calendar API->Credentials->Domain Verification.

No error. Sends me to Webmaster Central.

Comment: Here are some common reasons for this error:
1. Please remember it takes up to 48 hours for the domain to be verified.
2. Depending on which domain verification option you used, it's possible the required record was not created or entered correctly. For more details, please refer to here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071480?hl=en

Comment: The problem is that I'm unable to use the 2 options available, ie. CNAME and TXT verification, because, I'm on Heroku subdomain.

Although, I am able to verify the subdomain on Webmaster Tools outside of this process using Meta tag verification.

Meta tag verification is not an option from the first path.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Tobi, I did eventually resolve this, however, I'm unable to recall exactly what ended up working.